# Failed to execute 'send'': RTCDataChannel.readyState is not 'open'

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I'm making a video call + chat application with WebRTC on ReactJS. I got this error when trying to send messages between 2 peers

**Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': RTCDataChannel.readyState is not 'open'**

I suppose it depends on how I setup my peer connection and dataChannel. Here is how I setup my dataChannel:

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.initial();
    }
    send(message) {
        if (connectedUser) {
            message.name = connectedUser;
        }
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    }
    initial() {
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, (myStream) => {
            stream = myStream;
            this.setState({localVideoSrc: window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)});
            var configuration = { 
                "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302" }] 
         }; 
         yourConn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration, {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]}); 
         yourConn.addStream(stream);
         yourConn.onaddstream = (e) => {
             this.setState({remoteVideoSrc: window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream)});
         };
         this.send({
            type: "update"
         });
         yourConn.onicecandidate = (event) => {
            if (event.candidate) {
                this.send({
                    type: "candidate",
                    candidate: event.candidate
                });
            }
         };
         dataChannel = yourConn.createDataChannel("channel1", {reliable:true}); 
         console.log("dataChannel:", dataChannel);
         dataChannel.onerror = (error) => {
             console.log("Ooops...error:", error);
         };

         //when we receive a message from the other peer, display it on the screen
         dataChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
             var oldMessages = this.state.receivedMessage;
             var userB = this.state.callToUser;
             this.setState({
                 receivedMessage: oldMessages + userB + ": " + event.data + "<br />"
             })
         };

         dataChannel.onclose = () => {
             console.log("data channel is closed");
         };
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks a bunch!

**Update:** 1. `yourConn` is a variable which I was declared on top my component as: `var yourConn`

2. variable `conn` was imported from another file. Here is the file

   export var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090');

   conn.onopen = () => {
       console.log('Connected to the signaling server');
   };
   conn.onerror = (err) => {
       console.log("Got error", err);
   };
   conn.onmessage = (msg) => {
       if (msg.data === "Hello world") {
           console.log("Got message", msg.data);
       }
   };

Comment: Can you show more code. Where is `conn`, `yourConn` declared ?

Comment: sure, I'll update my question